# Require Authentication for directory (except one page) with Passport.js / Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm new to using Passport.js, but I find it's going pretty well so far. I'm using Passport with passport-local.

However, I want to require authentication for an entire directory excluding one page. So in my node server I'm serving up this direcory like so (using express):

```
app.use("/admin", express.static(__dirname + "/admin"));
```

And then I want to let the user hit /admin/login.html, so I wanted to do something like this:

```
app.get('/gb-admin/login.html', function(req, res){ });
```

Then I want to require authentication for the rest, so something like this:

```
app.get('/gb-admin/*', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){});
```

Here is my ensureAuthenticated function, for reference if it helps:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/gb-admin/login.html')
}
```

How would I go about doing this? I've been generally sending things in infinite loops and causing the browser to timeout. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting timeouts is because you can't have an empty route handler; at one point, you *have* to either return a response, or hand the request over the the next route handler/middleware.

That said, try this:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path === '/gb-admin/login.html' || req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/gb-admin/login.html')
}

app.get('/gb-admin/*', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});

// the static middleware needs to be declared after the route above, otherwise
// it will take precedence and ensureAuthenticated will never be called.
app.use("/gb-admin", express.static(__dirname + "/admin"));
```

I don't think there's a way to get it working with a separate route for the login page (unless you actually implement reading `login.html` and sending it back from without that routes handler), hence the check for it in the `ensureAuthenticated` middleware.

Comment: Ah, this is great! Thanks! Helps me understand what's going on here too.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is your callback. Try:

```
app.get('/gb-admin/*', function (req, res, next) {
  ensureAuthentication(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/gb-admin/login.html')
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help too! I haven't tested you solution, as @robertklep had posted his answer first, which worked so I stuck with it. Thank you for your help though!